Flink Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(pekko://flink/deadLetters), Path(/)]
On my kubernetes cluster I have flink-kubernetes-operator 1.7.0 and apache-flink 1.18.1 installed. I came across an issue when I installed FlinkDeployment CR (custom resrouce) into a namespace named 0525-flink.
The job manager pod throws below error:
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.RpcConnectionException: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.0525flink:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_*.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcService.lambda$resolveActorAddress$10(PekkoRpcService.java:562) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF$$anon$1.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:67) ~[?:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.RpcConnectionException: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.0525flink:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_*.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcService.lambda$resolveActorAddress$10(PekkoRpcService.java:562) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF$$anon$1.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:67) ~[?:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(pekko://flink/deadLetters), Path(/)]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorSelection.$anonfun$resolveOne$1(ActorSelection.scala:84) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.internal.SameThreadExecutionContext$$anon$1.unbatchedExecute(SameThreadExecutionContext.scala:31) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:140) ~[?:?]

and also observed similar errors in task-manager pod:
org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.RpcConnectionException: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.0525flink:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcService.lambda$resolveActorAddress$10(PekkoRpcService.java:562) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF$$anon$1.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:67) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF$$anon$1.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:61) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(pekko://flink/deadLetters), Path(/)]
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorSelection.$anonfun$resolveOne$1(ActorSelection.scala:84) ~[?:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.internal.SameThreadExecutionContext$$anon$1.unbatchedExecute(SameThreadExecutionContext.scala:31) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:140) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:134) ~[?:?]

Seems the issue occurs with the address pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.0525flink:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_* being passed at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/26e8031b04043fe3f4cb6163d3a66852d4795a88/flink-rpc/flink-rpc-akka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/rpc/pekko/PekkoRpcService.java#L548 when the ActorSystem tree is getting created.
I tried installing in different namespace flink-0525 and the installation completed successfully for both job-manager and task-manager.
2024-05-26 20:01:48,280 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Connecting to ResourceManager pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.flink-0525:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*(00000000000000000000000000000000).
2024-05-26 20:01:48,727 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Successful registration at resource manager pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.flink-0525:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_* under registration id 8c2b90afa7dd983c079ad9539a8907e6.

I am not a pekko/akka expert but looks like when the address is passed in ActorSystem.actorSelection(path) the parsing of the address is not happening as expected for a URL pekko://flink.01-bla:6123 but works in case of pekko://flink.bla-01:6123.
Not sure but https://github.com/apache/pekko/blob/v1.0.2/actor/src/main/scala/org/apache/pekko/actor/ActorPath.scala is where the path validation mostly is happening. Any help with this would be great.
Thanks in advance.

The RPC actor pekko.tcp://flink@flink-ssl.0525flink:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_* was supervised by SupervisorActor, you may want to confirmed the SupervisorActor was created, and the RpcActor creation was not expcetion thrown. Can you provide more logs?
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/30196294eb863a2ea288ea562812b9ebaffece12/flink-rpc/flink-rpc-akka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/rpc/pekko/PekkoRpcService.java#L353-L355

@Roiocam The issue seems to be when the uri flink-ssl.0525flink was getting parsed, it was not liking a number for example 0525 after the . but wouldn't have an issue if an alphabet followed the . in the uri. Was able to get the root cause code and fixed it from there https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/30196294eb863a2ea288ea562812b9ebaffece12/flink-kubernetes/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/kubernetes/kubeclient/decorators/InternalServiceDecorator.java#L77. Thanks!
